# Why does presentModalViewController not always work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My application requires data from a server in order to run.  The first thing it does is displays a view controller (LoadingViewController) that is responsible for checking if the data is saved to my PersistentStoreCoordinator.  If the data isn't cached locally, it gets it from my server and caches it, and posts a notification that the LoadingViewController is listening for.  When that notification comes through, LoadingViewController presents the application's MainViewController using the presentModalViewController with a flip animation.  So far, so good... no errors.

However, if the application loads and determines the data IS cached - the presentModalViewController does not work and the main application view never appears.  No errors.  I've even gone as far as adding a button to the Loading view that executes the same code when pressed and the damn thing works.

I'm suspicious it has something to do with the timing of it all but I'm clueless as to what I can do to ensure the view is displayed with that flipping animation if the data is already cached locally.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So I ended up using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay ( [self performSelector:@selector(showApp) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0]; ) with a delay of 0 and it works now.  I'm not thrilled, because it seems like a really lazy and ugly way to get things done - but mostly because I still do not understand why it wasn't working just by calling [self showApp]

Comment: Post your code.  Someone might be able to help.

Comment: I was having a similar problem and, yep, this performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: actually works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay ( [self performSelector:@selector(showApp) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0]; ) with a delay of 0 and it works now. I'm not thrilled, because it seems like a really lazy and ugly way to get things done - but mostly because I still do not understand why it wasn't working just by calling [self showApp]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a deep hierarchy of view controllers' views subviewed into one another, then always try to present with immediately viewcontroller whose view is directly added to the window of ur iphone app.

For e.g. I had 4 levels of view like
window > vc1's view > vc2's view > vc3's view

So when I tried to call [vc3 presentModalViewController] it was not working..
I had to present with vc1 and it worked. I had vc1 referenced as a property to app delegate and hence was able to access easily.

But again, I didn't still find the actual reason, but I can say this worked for me.